# Detect via Apex/Visualforce if org has MyDomain enabled

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, mydomain

I have some customer orgs that still work on Classic and didn't enable MyDomain. This causes strange errors. **Is there a way I can check with Apex if an org has a MyDomain enabled?**

Comment: this might help --> [How to determine instance via APEX on a My Domain?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092a6IAA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just check:

```
Boolean isMyDomainEnabled = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().endsWith('my.salesforce.com');
```

Or maybe:

```
Boolean isMyDomainEnabled = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().contains('--');
```

That should return true for all orgs with MyDomain enabled, as the url format there would be `domain--sandbox.cs42.my.salesforce.com`. In orgs without, it would just be `cs42.salesforce.com`.

Comment: I have orgs without "my" in their mydomain.

Comment: What about checking `.contains('--')`?

Answer (score 4):

Try `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();`. In some cases you might also get useful info out of a query such as `[SELECT fullPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE userType = 'Standard' LIMIT 1]`.

Credit to Cristophe Coenrats for both. His repo here https://github.com/ccoenraets/lightning-component-apex-continuation contains code that allows Apex continuations in Lightning, and as a result his Visualforce and Lightning components need to successfully guess each other's base URLs in order to communicate successfully.